# Spotfire Drop Down List Unfiltered Values

Tags: spotfire

I have a drop down list in my text area. How do I only show the unfiltered values of a column in this list?

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to do this. Posting it here if anyone needs it.

One way is to create a separate data table using a data function that uses the primary data table as the input and then base your property control on that data table.